# Django - Image not being displayed in the webpage

Tags: django

In my project, I have a `DetailView`, so a user can view their profile. On here, I want to display their profile picture. However when I open the browser and go to the **detail page**, no profile picture is displayed. My code is displayed below.

**models.py**:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    profilePic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics/', default='static/default-profile.png')
```

**views.py**:

```
class DetailProfile(generic.DetailView):
    model = User
    # Template that a users profile picture should be displayed in
    template_name = 'detail_profile.html'
```

**detail_profile.html**:

```
<img width="200px"  src="{{ user.profilePic.url }}" alt="">
```

**Error returned by the browser**:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/media/static/default-profile.png 404 (Not Found)
```

**urls.py (for the `users` apps)**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('resetone/', views.resetone, name='resetone'),
    path('resetwo/', views.resetwo, name='resetwo'),
    path('viewprofile/<int:pk>', views.DetailProfile.as_view(), name='detail_profile'),
]  + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**SETTINGS.PY**:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'proj2/static/')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Currently, all the users have the file `default-profile.png` assigned to their profile pic, however later I am going to implement the ability for users to change their profile pic.

`default-profile.png`  is stored in the static folder(Check my settings.py code above), and is also assigned to a user when they first **signup**. Does anybody know why this file isn't being displayed in the browser and why I am getting returned the error displayed above? Thank you.

Comment: One of possible solutions is to put the file where Django expects to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have been trying the wrong url.
As you are uploading them to `profile_pics/` , then all media uploaded resides in the `profile_pics` directory which should probably be in the root directory.
The correct url for the following would be :-
`http://localhost:8000/media/profile_pics/yourimagename.jpg`

Comment: Ah ok Great! Thanks.